# gdb if condition syntax error

Tags: fortran, gdb

I have a really simple Fortran program in a file test.f90:

```
program test
   real :: x
   x=12
   write(*,*) x
end program test
```

I compile it with

```
gfortran -g test.f90
```

Then I try with gdb:

```
gdb a.out
break 4 if a == 12
```

but I get

```
A syntax error in expression, near `= 12'.
```

I found several docs and forums saying this should work, but it doesn't...
What is the correct syntax for this simple condition?
I use gdb 7.6.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for gdb has the following [to say about Fortran support](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Fortran.html):

> GDB can be used to debug programs written in Fortran, but it currently supports only the features of Fortran 77 language.

As the logical conditional `x == 12` is Fortran 90 pedigree you can instead write

```
break 4 if x.eq.12
```