# Fortran debugging in VSCode, conditional breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gdb

What is the correct syntax to set conditional breakpoints in VSCode for fortran, I tried `if k.eq.6` and `if k==6` and that does not work, by which I mean, the code doesn't break even if the condition is met. I get the error "a syntax error in expression near ..." Where ... is everything after the if.

The compiler I use is mpifort, which is a fortran compiler that comes with MPICH (for parallel computing), however I'm not debugging in parallel.
Plugins are : Fortran breakpoint support, GDB Debugger - Beyond and Modern Fortran

Comment: What debugger/plugin are you using? Please do not just write "it does not work", say what happened when you tried it.

Comment: What if you try just `k==6` without the `if`?

Comment: And which compiler are you using? VSCode, by itself, doesn't understand languages at all. You need to add in compiler support. I don't know of Fortran compilers that work in VSCode (not saying there aren't any, but I'm not familiar with this combination.)

Comment: if i use without the if, i get an error when I hover over the breakpoint in the breakpoints tab , : A syntax error in expression near '=6'.

Comment: `mpifort` is just a wrapper, the real compiler is hidden. You should find it using `mpifort -show`.

Comment: Acording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829796/gdb-if-condition-syntax-error), the correct GDB command is `break X if foo.eq.bar`. Assuming the plugin adds `if` for you, have you tried `k.eq.6` (without `if`)?

Comment: `mpifort -show` outputs this, I am not sure what it means. `f95 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpichfort -lmpich`

Comment: @HristoIliev you are right! Thank you so much!

Comment: It means that when you call `mpifort`, the line `f95 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpichfort -lmpich` is executed for you. The compiler is called using `f95` but that is again just a symlink (I assume you are using Ubuntu) and points to `gfortran`.